# Long String vs StringBuilder variations performance

Tags: java, string, optimization

Hello I've seen several ways of creating Strings and I'd like to know which one is faster i.e. has better performance between

```
String a ="Hello sick sad world! 213763e83456382582463456";
```

or

```
String a =new String("Hello sick sad world! 213763e83456382582463456");
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello sick sad world! 213763e83456382582463456");
String a = sb.toString();
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello");
sb.append(" sick");
sb.append(" sad");
sb.append(" world!");
sb.append(" 213763e83456382582463456");
String a = sb.toString();
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello").append(" sick").append(" sad").append(" world!").append(" 213763e83456382582463456");
String a = sb.toString();
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` is only useful if you're composing a `String` dynamically from parts that you do not know at compile-time. No reason to use it as you suggest here..

Comment: Each of the examples does something different.What is the *real* problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: remove extra spaces in the last piece of code that defeats the idea of this Question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is:

- 1 - fastest
- 2 - 2nd fastest
- 3 - 3rd fastest
- 4 & 5 - equal last

In fact, if you ignore the overheads of code loading, etcetera, the first example reduces to a single pointer assignment.  You can't improve on that.

The other examples all involve the creation of at least one new object.

Comment: While this is true, I think it's worth noting that 1, 2 and 3 are going to be almost identical for all but the most extreme workloads (`new String(String)` is just a constant-time operation), while 3 and 4 are going to be significantly slower (they require copying all of the chars twice).

Comment: If the string is not already in the pool, how can 1 be faster than 2?

Comment: @yshavit - Pointer assignment of an N character string is O(1).  Copying of an N character strings O(N).

Comment: @MickMnemonic - Pointer assignment is O(1) and string copying is O(N) whether or not the strings are in the string pool.  (Assuming we are talking about current generation Java String implementations.)

Comment: Let me clarify: If the program is only run once, the 1st version has to both create the string and `intern` it. How can it be faster than only creating the string in the 2nd version?

Comment: @StephenC I misread case 3 in the OP -- I thought it was `new String("...").toString()`, not `new StringBuilder(...).toString()`. Other than that, I think your comment is fully consistent with mine, no?

Comment: @MickMnemonic - Correction.  The second version also has to intern the string.  The interning happens when the class containing the string literal is loaded.  In fact, all of the examples have string literals, and all of the string literals need to be interned when the respective code is loaded.

Comment: Yes, of course. That makes sense.

Comment: @yshavit - I don't agree that what you said is consistent with what I said. You said that new String(String) is a constant time operation. It isn't for current generation String implementations. Besides, big O notation is not a measure of performance. It is a characterization of how performance scales as a particular scaling parameter changes. Even if A and B are both O(1), you can't infer that they perform the same.

Comment: (Actually Big O notation is really about the behavior of abstract functions.  In algorithmic complexity theory, we are *applying* the notation to functions that measure / predict something that is performance related.  It would be mathematically sound to use the notation in other domains that have nothing to do with performance.)

Comment: @StephenC In my JDK 8, `new String(String)` is just `this.value = original.value; this.hash = original.hash`. Are you maybe thinking of the `substring` methods, which used to share the backing `char[]` but made a copy starting in Java 7? The extra cost of `new String(String)` is one allocation and two field assignments; for most usages, there probably isn't going to be a noticeable difference.

Comment: Ah ... I was going from memory.  But even so, `new String(String)` is still likely to take an order of magnitude longer than a pointer assignment.  And even more if you factor in garbage collection.  Sure, we still talking nano-seconds, but using `new String(String)` has ZERO benefit except in very unusual use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

String is a wired and cool thing is Java.

1. reuses an existing String object with `"Hello sick sad world! 213763e83456382582463456"`if there is any.
2. allocate new memory and add the value `"Hello sick sad world! 213763e83456382582463456"`.
3. First create a `StringBuilder` object with the value `"Hello sick sad world! 213763e83456382582463456"` and then during the toString() method, it starts allocate memory and assign the value inside the StringBuilder implementation.

4,5 are the same thing, But a matter of short code.

StringBuilder and String are used in different cases, StringBuilder is there to make String manipulation efficient. Since String behaves Immutable, you can achieve the mutable behavior from String builder.

The answer to your question is either 1 or 2. If you have a hit in the pool of string objects, 1 is faster than 2, if not 2 is faster than 1.

Comment: Can you explain why you think, that 2 is faster, if there isn't a matching String in the pool? (which isn't the case btw.)